# AngularJS - Filter not working on data that hasnt been scrolled to

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a simple `ng-repeat` that uses a scroll directive. On load, the first 10 results are displayed, on `scoll`, more results are show.

The issue i am seeing is that when you type a value in the input, the data that is filtered seems to be the data that is displayed at the current time.

So in the example in my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1qR6CucQdsGqYnVvk70A?p=preview

If you type in **Last** in the textbox after loading the page (do not scroll), that data is never shown. However, if you scroll to the bottom, then type **Last**, that result is found.

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed" directive-when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit | filter: search">{{ i.Title }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>


<input ng-model="searchText">
<button ng-click="performSearch(searchText)">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {  

$scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.limit = 5;


  var counter = 0;
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.limit += 5;
  };

  $scope.loadMore();

  $scope.performSearch = function(searchText) {
        $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.search);
    }

    $scope.search = function (item){
        if (!$scope.searchText)
            return true;

        if (item.Title.indexOf($scope.searchText)!=-1 || item.Title.indexOf($scope.searchText)!=-1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    };


});


app.directive("directiveWhenScrolled", function() {
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
      if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
        scope.$apply(attr.directiveWhenScrolled);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the filter *before* you limit the results:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | filter: search | limitTo: limit">{{ i.Title }}</li>
```